# Ошибка при использовании M_PI

Tags: c++

IDE подчеркивает, как ошибку, фрагмент `a = M_PI / 4`, в чем может быть причина?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define  USE_MATH_DEFINES

int main()
{
    float a = M_PI / 4;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ***оно*** -- что это? (у меня ни emacs, ни g++ -Wall ничего в этом коде не отметили)

Comment: Обычно, если навести курсор на подчеркнутое, можно почитать описание причин подчеркивания.

Answer (score 9):

- Используйте вместо `USE_MATH_DEFINES` макрос `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` (начинается со знака подчёркивания).
- Макрос должен быть определён до включения заголовочного файла `math.h`.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

...

std::cout << M_PI;
```

Константа `M_PI` не определяется стандартом языка C++, а является расширением некоторых компиляторов. И для её использования не всегда требуется определение `_USE_MATH_DEFINES`.

Начиная со стандарта C++20 доступен заголовочный файл `<numbers>` в котором определены различные [математические константы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) всех типов с плавающей точкой (`float`, `double`, `long double`), включая число π.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>
#include <limits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_digits10);
    
    cout << "pi<double>:      " << std::numbers::pi                << endl;
    
    cout << "pi<float>:       " << std::numbers::pi_v<float>       << endl;
    cout << "pi<double>:      " << std::numbers::pi_v<double>      << endl;
    cout << "pi<long double>: " << std::numbers::pi_v<long double> << endl;
}
```

Возможный [вывод программы](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/175a2276045136b4):

```
pi<double>:      3.141592653589793116
pi<float>:       3.14159274101257324219
pi<double>:      3.141592653589793116
pi<long double>: 3.14159265358979323851
```